# What statistical test should I use for my experiment?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, panel-data

I am doing an experiment on the effect of temperature on the rate of lactic acid fermentation of yoghurt over 6 hours. I have used the fall in pH as an indicator for the presence of lactic acid. I have measured the pH of yoghurt every hour for 5 sets of temperatures and calculated the rate of fermentation for every hour. I have then calculated the mean rate of fermentation over the 6 hours and I want to prove there are significant differences between the mean rate of fermentation at different temperatures.

But I'm not sure what statistical tests I could use, as I realise that I cannot use a t-test because the rate of fermentation for every hour is not normally distributed. So what possible stat tests I can use?

*12 trials for each temperature*

Comment: Do you have one sample of yoghurt at each temperature?

Comment: **12 trials for each temperature** ( I lost the previous account and couldn't post a comment)

Comment: Please visit http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts to merge your accounts.

Comment: Try the non-parametric version of the ANVOA, which is not as powerful but could be safer here: Kruskal-Wallis Test.